# showing contents of a table using PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I have this code snippet:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=judges", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM feedback";


echo '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">Judge Name</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">PC</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">TD</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">EX</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">ID</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">comment</font> </td>
      </tr>';

if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    echo "got result";

    echo $result["PC"];
    //while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    while ($row = $result) {
        $field1name = $row["judgeName"];
        $field2name = $row["PC"];
        $field3name = $row["TD"];
        $field4name = $row["EX"];
        $field5name = $row["ID"]; 
        $field6name = $row["comment"];
 
        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field5name.'</td> 
                  <td>'.$field6name.'</td> 
              </tr>';
    }
}
```

both inside submit.php, however, while the feedback table inside judges database is not empty, I don't see any of the rows shown in the HTML page only the column name shows up in the Response tab of Network tab in Firefox Inspect tool. What do you suggest to populate the existing database into the html page even before I enter the information for the new user?

Here's my feedback table from the judges database:

[image]

Trying the following from the comments also didn't work and nothing got printed:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't echo `got result` without putting it inside `<tr>` and `<td>`.

Comment: Uncomment `//while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` and remove the other While

Comment: @RiggsFolly that didn't work, it tells it doesn't recognize the fetch_assoc() method

Comment: Oh right your using PDO not MySQLI

Comment: In PDO it's `while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

Comment: @RiggsFolly please check end of updated post. I added my database.

Comment: You should be getting an infinite loop with `while ($row = $result)`

Comment: `echo $result["PC"];` makes no sense. `$result` isn't an array, it should cause an error.

Comment: @Barmar my bad yeah removed `$result["PC"]` and used `while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` however, there's two caveats. The results are not shown until I submit a new entry by user using submit button and also the results are only shown in Response section of Network tab from Firefox Inspect tool, not on the HTML as intended by me. Thank you.

Comment: If they're showing in the network tab but not being displayed, it sounds like a problem with your JavaScript code that's processing the AJAX response. AJAX responses aren't displayed automatically, the JS has to add it to the DOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point in the `if` statement. You have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` enabled, so if there's an error in the query it will throw an exception, not return `false`.

The syntax to fetch a row in PDO is `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
echo "<td><tr>got result</tr></td>";

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $field1name = $row["judgeName"];
    $field2name = $row["PC"];
    $field3name = $row["TD"];
    $field4name = $row["EX"];
    $field5name = $row["ID"]; 
    $field6name = $row["comment"];
 
    echo '<tr> 
             <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 
             <td>'.$field2name.'</td> 
             <td>'.$field3name.'</td> 
             <td>'.$field4name.'</td> 
             <td>'.$field5name.'</td> 
             <td>'.$field6name.'</td> 
         </tr>';
}
```

Comment: do you know why results 1) are not shown in the HTML page itself 2) only shown after the user inputs a new entry via submit form and not before? I intend to see the results when the user accesses the page.

Comment: As I said above, if you're sending an AJAX request that returns this table, you need add the response to the DOM in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You were mixing PDO and MYSQLI_
Also you had some debug code that would have damaged your table HTML.

Also there is no real point in moving data from a perfectly good array into scalar variables just to include those values in some HTML.

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<tr> 
                  <td>$row[judgeName]</td> 
                  <td>$row[PC]</td> 
                  <td>$row[TD]</td> 
                  <td>$row[EX]</td> 
                  <td>$row[ID]</td> 
                  <td>$row[comment]</td> 
              </tr>";
    }
}
```